# The import org.apache.commons.codec cannot be resolved

Tags: java, import, jar, base64

I am configuring my development environment and I find I cannot import the following library.  I am trying to directly downloading the jar from Apache website but I haven´t found it yet. Unfortunately, I can´t use maven because this project uses ant tasks. Could you please help me in this search? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) is the link for the `Codec`component of `apache commons`.

There you can find documentations and releases. The actual download page can be found [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi).

[image]

There you have the jar files, you are looking for!